# Installing packages from source fails with "unexpected $end" error

Tags: r

This one is killing me:

Problem: I can't install any packages in R from source code using standard repositories.

```
install.packages("quantreg", type="source")
```

```
Installing package into ‘/Users/foo/Library/R/3.0/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.wustl.edu/src/contrib/quantreg_5.05.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1636075 bytes (1.6 Mb)
opened url

downloaded 1.6 Mb

Error: 1:5: unexpected $end
Execution halted

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/h3/yfhgnv7n5gq84ly4kr6334gr0000gn/T/Rtmp3kothF/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("quantreg", type = "source") :
```

```
options("unzip")
$unzip
[1] "internal"
```

Details

OS: OSX.9 
I made a clean install of Mavericks and installed Xcode 5 + command line tools.
R: 3.0.2 installed from CRAN binary

I realize that I could install binary packages for "quantreg", but that's not the point.

Question: How can I fix this?

I've tried:

1. installing R from source (actually, this is how I first noticed the problem)
   1b. installing R from source using clang and clang++
2. modifying /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/etc/Makeconf file to change CC and CXX to clang, clang++
3. Voodoo

Obviously, none of these things worked for me. Am I just doing something naively stupid? Use small words in simple sentences, please.

UPDATE:
Using the r-sig-mac archives, there was some stuff that was appropriate regarding the incredible, dissapearing GNUTAR. I also found on my own some problems with the gfortran call. I made some headway (but still not solved) by adding the following lines to my "/Users/foo/.R/Makevars" file

```
TAR=/usr/bin/tar
FC=/usr/local/bin/gfortran
F77=/usr/local/bin/gfortran
FLIBS =  -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin8/4.2.3/x86_64 -L/usr/local/lib/x86_64 -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin8/4.2.3
```

Note that this removes the "-lgfortran" option from FLIBS. 
Now, the packages will install using R CMD INSTALL /path/to/source.tar.gz (which is new), but still won't work using my original command in R.

Comment: There has been much recent discussion on the r-sig-mac list around R and Mavericks. Check there to see if any of the discussion there seems relevant to this problem.

Comment: I'd also recommend upgrading to R 3.0.2 & the latest R.app GUI to make sure things are copasthetic on your system.